# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json in postgres import

Tags: postgresql

I have taken a dump of postgres database from server, let's say abc.sql whose total size is 56 GB. I created a local database in postgres, let's say import_here where I have to import the abc.sql. I am using the following command to import:

```
sudo -u postgres psql import_here < abc.sql
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I have checked the validation of json using jsonlint and it was valid. I am working on ubuntu 20.04 and the postgres version is 10.51.

Comment: Please give text as text, not as images.  What comes after "266387670" in the last line?  What is the actual complete line of line number 3410048 of the file?

Comment: **COPY access_logs, line 3410048, column operations: "{"address": "", "passcode": "266387670", "syncedBy": "1ei0y4s00000000", "appVersion": "81", "unlockC..."** is the complete last line. The image consist of complete error.

Comment: Can you check the pg_dump version you used to create the SQL file, the psql version you're using to try to import the file and the Postgres server version you're using ?

Comment: -- Dumped from database version 10.15
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
-- Tried importing using version 12 and 10 both.